# Calculating difference of values between two dates with pyspark

Tags: sql, pyspark

My data is like this:

| year_month | user_id | pageviews | visits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-03 | 2 | 8 | 3 |
| 2021-03 | 27 | 4 | 3 |
| 2021-05 | 23 | 75 | 7 |
| 2020-05 | 23 | 17 | 7 |
| 2020-08 | 339 | 253 | 169 |
| 2020-08 | 892 | 31 | 4 |
| 2021-08 | 339 | 4 | 3 |

And I wanted to group by year_month calculating the difference of pageviews and visits from one year(2020) to the next(2021).

So, I was thinking the output should be something similar to (without the content inside the parenthesis):

| last_month | diff(pageviews) | diff(visits) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03 | -4(4-8) | 0(3-3) |
| 2021-05 | 58(75-17) | 0(7-7) |
| 2021-08 | -280(4-284) | -170(3-173) |

But I'm not sure how to do it vectorized, I was thinking of passing it to pandas and doing it with a for loop, but wanted to learn how to do this kind of things in a vectorized way with pyspark or sparksql that I think they will be much faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main idea is using window function to compare months. Check my comments for more explanations

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

(df
    # since you'd want to compare month and year separately,
    # we have to separate them out using split function
    .withColumn('year', F.split('year_month', '-')[0].cast('int'))
    .withColumn('month', F.split('year_month', '-')[1].cast('int'))
 
    # you have multiple rows per year_month
    # so we have to group and sum the similar records
    .groupBy('year', 'month')
    .agg(
        F.sum('pageviews').alias('pageviews'),
        F.sum('visits').alias('visits')
    )
    
    # now, you need to compare 2021's months with 2020's months,
    # you'd have to use lag window function, pay attention to the orderBy window
    .withColumn('prev_pageviews', F.lag('pageviews').over(W.orderBy('month', 'year')))
    .withColumn('prev_visits', F.lag('visits').over(W.orderBy('month', 'year')))

    # with current pageviews/visits and previous pageviews/visits on the same row
    # you can easily calculate the difference between months
    .withColumn('diff_pageviews', F.col('pageviews') - F.col('prev_pageviews'))
    .withColumn('diff_visits', F.col('visits') - F.col('prev_visits'))

    # select only necessary colums and rows
    .select('year', 'month', 'diff_pageviews', 'diff_visits')
    .where(F.col('year') == 2021)

    .show()
)

# Output
# +----+-----+--------------+-----------+
# |year|month|diff_pageviews|diff_visits|
# +----+-----+--------------+-----------+
# |2021|    3|            -4|          0|
# |2021|    5|            58|          0|
# |2021|    8|          -280|       -170|
# +----+-----+--------------+-----------+
```